# Use multiple functions in mutate efficiently in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I used mutate to add new variables in my dataframe. The code below is an example and in my real data I need to mutate `lag1` to `lag100` and `lag01` to `lag0100`. I don't want to type these one by one.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

```
c <- mtcars %>% mutate_all( .funs = list(lag1 = ~lag(., 1),
                                         lag2 = ~lag(., 2),
                                         lag3 = ~lag(., 3),
                                         lag4 = ~lag(., 4),
                                         lag5 = ~lag(., 5),
                                         lag6 = ~lag(., 6),
                                         lag01 = ~rollmean(., 2, fill = NA, align = 'right'),
                                         lag02 = ~rollmean(., 3, fill = NA, align = 'right'),
                                         lag03 = ~rollmean(., 4, fill = NA, align = 'right'),
                                         lag04 = ~rollmean(., 5, fill = NA, align = 'right'),
                                         lag05 = ~rollmean(., 6, fill = NA, align = 'right'),
                                         lag06 = ~rollmean(., 7, fill = NA, align = 'right')
                                         ))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `rollmean` from `zoo` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across` in new `dplyr` 1.0.0 to apply multiple functions to all columns.  `rollmean` with `align = 'right` is same as using `rollmeanr`. You can assign relevant names using `.names` specification.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(zoo)

x <- 5
map_dfc(1:x, function(i) mtcars %>% 
        transmute(across(.fns = list(lag = ~lag(., i), 
                   mean =  ~rollmeanr(., i + 1, fill = NA)), 
                   .names = paste0('{col}_{fn}_', i))))
```

Comment: Thanks @ Ronak, it' a nice way but little question about the new variable names. The new names suffix with `...1`, `...2`, `...3` just a number sequence and could not response to which number I passed to `lag` or `rollmeanr`. Is there a way to make the new name suffix is the argument that passed in `.fns` (etc, `mpg_lag1` when use `~ lag(., 1)` and `mpg_mean5` when use `~ rollmeanr(., 5+1, fill =NA)`)

Comment: Bother you again. I tried to use purrr-style rewrite the code but failed. `map_dfc(1:x, ~ mtcars %>% transmute(across(.fns = list(lag = ~lag(., .x), mean =  ~rollmeanr(., .x + 1, fill = NA)),  .names = paste0('{col}_{fn}', .x))))`. I meant to use `.` represent `mtcars` and `.x` represent `1:x` but failed.

Comment: Inside `across` you can use both `.` and `.x` and it means the same. So there is a conflict of scope when you use the purrr-style syntax in this case. Hence, I used anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

In the example that follows I have subset `mtcars` keeping only 20 rows and 5 columns.
The code uses `bind_cols/Map` to apply the functions `lag` and `rollmeanr` (`rollmean, align = "right"`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

bind_cols(
  mtcars[1:20, 1:5] %>% 
    mutate_all(.funs = Map(function(n) lag = ~lag(., n), 1:2)),
  mtcars[1:20, 1:5] %>% 
    mutate_all(.funs = Map(function(n) lag0 = ~rollmeanr(., n, fill = NA), 1:2)) %>%
    select(-(1:5))
)
```

Then it's a matter of assigning new column names.